# Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, unable to create a new native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I am creating new threads every 5 seconds and using `Threadpool exector.` I am making sure threads are getting closed. But I am getting

`Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.`

Is it happening because I am creating to many threads and not closing them? or creating new ones frequently?

Can someone please tell me IF I am doing anything wrong in the code?

```
public class API{
    private   MongoStoreExecutor executor = new MongoStoreExecutor(10,50);
    private class MongoStoreExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
        public MongoStoreExecutor(int queueSize, int maxThreadPoolSize) {
            super(10, maxThreadPoolSize, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize),
                new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        }
    }

    public TimerTask alertingPoolsData() throws Exception, UnknownHostException {
        TimeerTask task  = new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                Pools = alertingPools.values().toArray();
                List<Future<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(Pools.length);
                for (Object pool : Pools) {
                    tasks.add(executor.submit(new DataAccumulation(timeStartSecData,
                        timeEndSec,pool, jsonArrayResult,dataResult)));
                }
                for( Future<?> f: tasks) {
                    f.get(2 * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long interval = 5 * 1000L;
        tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,(interval - 
            (System.currentTimeMillis() % interval)), interval);
        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: can someone pleasee let me know whats causing the issue?

Comment: Why would you subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor` just to have a constructor invocation? That's bad practice and can cause you subtle programming errors down the line.

Comment: Have you checked how many running threads you have (maybe using `Thread.activeCount`? Also: *why* do you start new threads ever 5 seconds? Wouldn't it be possible to just re-use the same pool?

Comment: And why would you mix `Timer` and executor services? Use `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Nobody can help you based on the code you gave us. It gives no evidence of unbounded thread creation. Presumably you have set an appropriate maxThreadPoolSize. Your code does seem overly complex to me, therfore hard to debug.

Comment: This error suggests the OS is not providing you with enough resources.  You need to specify the OS.

Comment: http://devgrok.blogspot.com/2012/03/resolving-outofmemoryerror-unable-to.html

Answer (score 0):

My hunch has to do with the code that we can't see: I suspect that you're calling `alertingPoolsData` over and over again somewhere.  As a result, I suspect that you are scheduling that `TimerTask` over and over again.  Each one of those component `TimerTasks` is then repeatedly creating some unknown number of `Future<?>s` (one for each of the elements of `Pools`), each of which is going to your `MongoStoreExecutor`.

If all of the above is the case, you've got a positive first derivative on your thread count curve.  As a result, you're going to see a quadratic increase in your thread count over time.  You'll start hitting the [upper limits of your native threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481900/whats-the-maximum-number-of-threads-in-windows-server-2003) pretty quickly.

As suggested in the comments, you could easily modify your current implementation.  I'd suggest a combination of a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).