# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on "JavaFX Application Thread"

Tags: java, windows

Since today, my Java application that I'm working on started crashing. I tried rebooting my computer, installing a newer JVM, re-downloading all dependencies, but the crashes keep on happening.

They seem to happen when I load a new web site or the JavaFX `WebView`, but it's not deterministic. It happens sometimes. I'm not noticing any other instability problem with my computer.

The error message on `stdout` looks like this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7845b950, pid=1112, tid=0x00001cd8
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_172-b11) (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.172-b11 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x7845b950
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashman\hs_err_pid1112.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

while it also prints to `stderr`:

```
1   7845B950
2   7786E446
3   77735447
4   77735539
5   7775430F
6   7741BA8E
7   77D8AD47
8   77D8B6F3
9   77D8BAEC
10  77E616DC
11  77E61980
12  77F2CB92
13  77F2B7E3
```

and the full log is too long for Stack Overflow, so, here it is: https://gist.github.com/pupeno/bc838d8af0ef32db3a3d8746bc81f6a8

Comment: Hi Pupeno, you are using 32 bit version of jre, is the issue observed on 64 bit also? Do you have any test case that we can verify at our end?

Comment: No, the issue is not happening on 32 bit. Making a minimum reproduction of the issue won't be easy, but I'll try.