# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread ..recreate in windows

Tags: java, multithreading

I faced the below issue in my application 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

My development environment in windows 7 64bit and deployment environment in linux 64 bit. I could not recreate the issue in my local development environment. I got the below code which when I ran in linux server gave me the same error when thread 3993 was created. `ulimit -u` gave a count of 4096. So I am convinced that somewhere near this threshold new threads are not allowed to be created for the process/application/user.

However I couldn't recreate the issue in my windows development environment. I am curious what code would actually give me the thread threshhold in windows

```
public class ThreadLimitChecker
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    int count = 0; 
    while (true) 
    {
      count++; 
      new Thread(new Runnable() 
      {
        public void run() 
        {
          try 
          {
            Thread.sleep(10000000); 
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }).start(); 
      System.out.println("Thread #:" + count); 
    }
  }
}
```

Expected a thread number where exception occurs

Comment: this [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/300274/windows-7-limit-the-number-of-threads-that-a-process-creates) suggests that there is no such limit in windows7 (before the ressources run out)

Comment: For Linux, there is this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux

Comment: There's [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/481900/1678362) that relates too, and I think you might want to check [this answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481926/1678362).

Answer (score 5):

Since I found this topic also interesting, I did some research.

You'll find the following statement by [Mark Russinovich (CTO of Microsoft Azure by now) @ technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/):

> Unlike some UNIX variants, most resources in Windows have no fixed
>   upper bound compiled into the operating system, but rather derive
>   their limits based on basic operating system resources that I’ve
>   already covered. Process and threads, for example, require physical
>   memory, virtual memory, and pool memory, so the number of processes or
>   threads that can be created on a given Windows system is ultimately
>   determined by one of these resources, depending on the way that the
>   processes or threads are created and which constraint is hit first.

So it's just running until there are no resources left.

Since `ulimit` is more or less a piece of software which watches some metrics, there was (of course) a similar tool for Windows called [Windows System Resource Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Resource_Manager) (until Windows Server 2012) which was (according to Wikipedia) superseded by [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) (since Windows Server 2008).